# git command for path of local git repository

Tags: git, android-studio

what is the git command to see the path for local git repository? E.g.

My Directory: `C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProjectDirectory`

Git Location: `C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProjectDirectory\.git`

what is the git command to return `C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProjectDirectory\.git`?

Comment: @Joe yes this does, thank you

Answer (score -2):

Below is command to show current directory path but without **.git**

echo "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"

Comment: I don't think the `echo $(...)` adds anything here. From the dupe, consider `git rev-parse --git-dir` to print it _with_ the `.git`, as requested.

Comment: your command doesnot return directory name.It jsut shows .git . Try run your command in git system

Comment: @Joe `--absolute-git-dir`